# anchor tag issue

Tags: tags, anchor

In My jsp page having lot many anchor tags. When I click on a anchor tag.Remaining all anchor tag getting red color itself. But it is working fine in IE 7 & 8. but fire fox alone am facing this issue. please any one can guide me.thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

You have messed up your html. Try to reorganise and clean up your jsp code.